# Warning with having apostrophe in #error preprocessor directive

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

If I try to compile a file (error_c11.cpp), whose contents are:

```
 #if 0
 #error This shouldn't be a problem
 #endif
```

With the command line:

```
gcc error_c11.cpp
```

I get the following warning (and then some other linker errors about main):

```
error_c11.cpp:2:20: warning: missing terminating ' character
 #error This shouldn't be a problem
```

Conversely, compiling the same with `clang` or Visual Studio does not give any warnings. Is this a bug in `gcc` (using v4.9.3), or, are `'` characters not allowed in `#error` preprocessor directives, and other compilers are more permissive?

Comment: According to the grammar, it's # error *pp-tokens newline*, where *pp-tokens* is one or more *preprocessing-token*, which includes *character-literal*. I could see this being invalid syntax.

Comment: Well, it's a _warning_ actually. Seems like even the c-preprocessor tends to go for AI capabilities on static code analysis.

Comment: Try to put your message in double quotes.

Comment: @KirillKobelev, Testing with Clang, that causes the error to quote the error message, which isn't ideal, but it's close.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax for a `#error` directive is:

**`#`** **`error`** *pp-tokens*<sub>*opt*</sub> *new-line*

A *pp-token* is a preprocessor token. An apostrophe can appear in a preprocessor token only if it's part of a character constant (or a string literal, or possibly a header name).

The tokens following `#error` don't have to be syntactically correct, but they do have to be valid tokens.

A workaround:

```
#if 0
#error "This shouldn't be a problem"
#endif
```

You could even write:

```
#if 0
#error This shouldn't be a problem, m'kay?
#endif
```

In that case, `'t be a problem, m'` is treated as a multi-character constant, which is nonsense but legal in this context.

(A digression: Attempts to apply the C preprocessor to Ada code have run into similar problems, since Ada uses a single apostrophe to introduce an attribute or qualified expression.)

Comment: This strikes me as the kind of thing that should be on cppreference.com, all it says is ["error_message can consist of several words not necessarily in quotes."](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/error)  I had to do a few searches before coming to this answer, because I was wondering if quotes should be favored, and this seems a solid argument for doing it.  Sadly, the quoting messes with multi-line error messages where you need to break it with a backslash because you get each string having its own quotes around it...I'm not optimistic that there's a workaround for that.  :-/